# Mouse Enter/Leave messages not working?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, mouseevent, delphi-xe2, windows-messages

I'm trying to detect mouse enter/leave messages `CM_MOUSEENTER` and `CM_MOUSELEAVE` but it isn't catching it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;

procedure TMyControl.CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  //Handle mouse entering
  //Breakpoint never reached, procedure never called
end;

procedure TMyControl.CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  //Handle mouse leaving
  //Breakpoint never reached, procedure never called
end;

procedure TMyControl.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
var
  Ch: Bool;
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    Message.Result := HTCLIENT
  else begin
    Ch:= False;

    //Do checks and pass `Ch:= True;` if something changed...

    if Ch then Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: My first comment is don't use breakpoints for monitoring such stuff. UI interaction is always messed up when you switch into the debugger. Use something like Codesite to send a message to another window, and be sure not to change focus while monitoring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out my issue: I'm also using `WM_NCHITTEST`, where I was NOT passing `inherited;`. I added this, and now it works fine.

Comment: `Wm_NCHitTest` seems like the wrong place for that anyway. It's a message the OS sends when it wants to know what part of a control a certain point represents. It doesn't even mean the mouse is currently *on* that point. What's that got to do with checking whether anything changed? Maybe you want `wm_MouseMove`? Or just call `Invalidate` as soon as something changes, so you don't have check later at all.

Comment: It's my own internal checking, it's about 30 lines of code which is checking the position to see if it is over a valid position - exactly what it's meant to do. I figured that part was irrelevant so I excluded it and replaced it with a comment.

Comment: If you're doing something other than deciding what value to assign to `Message.Result`, then you're doing it in the wrong message handler. Also, note that with the change you've described in your answer, you'll only return a valid value to the OS when nothing has changed. You should consider simply calling `inherited` unconditionally at the top of the function. Then you can remove the special assignment after checking `ComponentState` and just exit instead.